# handle Generic Model saving with signal django

Tags: python, django, django-signals

Here is my code

erp/partner/models.py

```
class BimaErpPartner(AbstractModel):
    GENDER_CHOICES = [(gender.value, gender.name) for gender in Gender]
    STATUS_CHOICES = [(status.value, status.name) for status in EntityStatus]
    PARTNER_TYPE_CHOICES = [(partner_type.value, partner_type.name) for partner_type in PartnerType]
    COMPANY_TYPE_CHOICES = [(company_type.value, company_type.name) for company_type in CompanyType]

    is_supplier = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    partner_type = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
    company_type = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    social_security_number = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=False)
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=False)
    Email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    Phone = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    Fax = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    company_activity = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    vat_id_number = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    note = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    addresses = GenericRelation(BimaCoreAddress, related_name='addresses')
    contacts = GenericRelation(BimaCoreContact, related_name='contacts')
    documents = GenericRelation(BimaCoreDocument, related_name='documents')
```

in erp/partner/signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=BimaErpPartner)
@transaction.atomic
def create_partner_related_entities(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print("aaaa")
    if created:
        addresses_data = instance.address_data
        if addresses_data:
            addresses = create_addresses(addresses_data, instance)
            BimaCoreAddress.objects.bulk_create(addresses)

        contacts_data = getattr(instance, 'contact_data', [])
        if contacts_data:
            contacts = create_contacts(contacts_data, instance)
            BimaCoreContact.objects.bulk_create(contacts)

        documents_data = getattr(instance, 'document_data', [])
        if documents_data:
            documents = create_documents(documents_data, instance)
            BimaCoreDocument.objects.bulk_create(documents)


def create_addresses(addresses_data, partner):
    addresses = []
    for address_data in addresses_data:
        address_serializer = BimaCoreAddressSerializer(data=address_data)
        address_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        address = address_serializer.save(entity=partner)
        addresses.append(address)
    return addresses


def create_contacts(contacts_data, partner):
    contacts = []
    for contact_data in contacts_data:
        contact_serializer = BimaCoreContactSerializer(data=contact_data)
        contact_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        contact = contact_serializer.save(entity=partner)
        contacts.append(contact)
    return contacts


def create_documents(documents_data, partner):
    documents = []
    for document_data in documents_data:
        document_serializer = BimaCoreDocumentSerializer(data=document_data)
        document_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        document = document_serializer.save(entity=partner)
        documents.append(document)
    return documents
```

here the
core/address/models.py

```
class BimaCoreAddress(AbstractModel):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=28, blank=False)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    street2 = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=28, blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
    state = models.ForeignKey(BimaCoreState, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    country = models.ForeignKey(BimaCoreCountry, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    parent_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={
            'model__in': [
                model._meta.model_name for model in apps.get_models()
                if model._meta.model_name not in ['bimacoreaddress']
            ]
        }
    )
    parent_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('parent_type', 'parent_id')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.number}, {self.city}, {self.street}, {self.zip}, {self.country}, {self.state}"

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['number']
        permissions = []
```

and here the .json file that I post

```
{
    "is_supplier": false,
    "is_customer": true,
    "partner_type": "INDIVIDUAL",
    "company_type": "SOLE_PROPRIETORSHIP",
    "first_name": "Radhoine",
    "last_name": "MEHAI",
    "gender": "MALE",
    "social_security_number": "123456",
    "id_number": "456789",
    "Email": "test@me.you",
    "Phone": "1479",
    "Fax": "12254",
    "company_name": "My Company",
    "company_activity": "Petrol",
    "vat_id_number": "14852369",
    "status": null,
    "note": "ACTIVE",
    "address_data" : [{
            "number": "456789",
            "street": "test@me.you",
            "street2": "1479",
            "zip": "12254",
            "city": "My Company",
            "state": "2058c7fe-44ac-4f56-b342-af13b9258b2f",
            "country": "efa266dd-2393-4a19-8fa4-90720c19219e"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not able to access address_data in the signal file
I need to save address_data in the AddressModel

what i'm doing wrong?

I triyed to change the way that I get address like this

```
 address= getattr(instance, 'address_data', [])
```

also I also tried

```
 addresses_data = instance.addresses.all()
```

still no data recived,
so any kind of help will be greatful